# Responsive page problem using Grid and Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I start a project and I'm trying to make it responsive without using @media.
I'm using flexbox and grid but for the hero background I have the text on the left and on the right side I have a image which is overlapping the text when the size of the screen is getting smaller.
What I want to do is when the size is getting smaller the image to go under the text no overlapping.

https://codepen.io/claudiuu/pen/PowVQvL

```
 * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "logo logo logo nav nav nav"
    "hero hero hero hero hero hero";
  background: rgb(233, 98, 123);
  background: linear-gradient(
    63deg,
    rgba(233, 98, 123, 1) 0%,
    rgba(191, 79, 212, 1) 100%
  );
}

.logo,
.nav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.hero {
  grid-area: hero;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: 50vh;
  padding: 6vmax;
  color: #fff;
}

.h1-hero {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.txthero {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 30vmax;
  min-width: 40vmin;
}

.img-hero {
  grid-area: hero;
  display: flex;
  background-image: url(https://www.apple.com/uk/music/images/overview/hero__drdt6ucq1rqu_small.png);
  background-position: center right;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15em, 1fr));
  /* background-color: rgb(233, 98, 123); */
  margin: 1.5rem;
  gap: 3em;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bg-box {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

Comment: You have the two grid areas that make up the hero section (`.hero` and `.img-hero`) using the same grid area name (`grid-area: hero`). Consider splitting both sections into distinct grid areas. You may also want to consider sourcing the image in the HTML, not the CSS. Both adjustments will give you more control over placement and behavior.

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you very much for replay. The point is I want to keep the image in CSS not in HTML. After few hour of changing code and thinking I figure out how I have to do. https://codepen.io/claudiuu/pen/yLyZQdP

Answer (score 0):

Updated code after few hours of thinking

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15em, 1fr));
  background: rgb(233, 98, 123);
  background: linear-gradient(
    63deg,
    rgba(233, 98, 123, 1) 0%,
    rgba(191, 79, 212, 1) 100%
  );
}

.logo,
.nav {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1rem;
}


.nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.grid-hero {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15em, 1fr));
  background: rgb(233, 98, 123);
  background: linear-gradient(
    63deg,
    rgba(233, 98, 123, 1) 0%,
    rgba(191, 79, 212, 1) 100%
  );
  padding: 2rem;
}

.txthero {  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.img-hero {
  /* min-height: 40vh; */
  margin: 1rem;
  height: 30vmin;
  background-image: url(https://www.apple.com/uk/music/images/overview/hero__drdt6ucq1rqu_small.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;  
  background-position: center;
}


.main-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(15em, 1fr));
  /* background-color: rgb(233, 98, 123); */
  margin: 1.5rem;
  gap: 3em;
  justify-content: center;
}

.bg-box {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

https://codepen.io/claudiuu/pen/yLyZQdP